# Saving and recalling an image with a placeholder image as default in android

Tags: android, image, view, bitmap, camera

I currently have a questionnaire, where each question is added dynamically in a db, which the app then receives for instructions. When it uses the camera, it sets the image just fine, using the code:

```
void setResponse(Bitmap image) {
    captureButton.setImageBitmap(image);
}
```

Simple enough, right? When I click update, to save it to the sqlite db, I save it as a base64 string using this:

```
String getResponse() {
    String response = "";
     try 
        {
           Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(captureButton.getDrawingCache());
           ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
           bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream);
           byte[] image = stream.toByteArray();
           response = Base64.encodeToString(image, 0);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {   
           Log.e("Capture image error", e.getMessage());
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
     return response;
}
```

And then when I go back into the questionnaire, if it has data already, it just loads it up using this:

```
void setResponse(String response) {
    byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(response, Base64.DEFAULT);
    Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
    captureButton.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
}
```

I currently have pretty much the same system for signatures using the gestureOverlayView. But for this, I have a placeholder image defined in the CameraQuestionView.xml file:

```
  <ImageView
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_margin="10dp"
   android:src="@drawable/placeholder"
   android:id="@+id/cameraQuestionCaptureButton"/>
```

But for some reason, when loading back up, the placeholder image is displayed instead of the saved image in the db. I tried invalidating the view, but that didn't work either.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried without setting the placeholder on the xml? Has the same effect (the ImageView didn't appear?)?

Comment: Ah! Yeah, it doesn't appear! I thought it would've. Seems to be not setting it in the db then, if that's the case, and placeholder's not actually doing the harm. Guess my question should change to, why isn't it saving it in the db, lol?

Comment: LoL , maybe :) ... try to debug the setResponse method, also you can try to load a Bitmap from your resources just to test if the setImageBitmap is working after all

Comment: Ok, it took me ages to track it down. I had to debug every line when it sets the response, it was setting no  text, so I checked if it was receiving anything from the db, and there wasn't an entry, so I checked a bunch of other stuff, and lo behold! It was something incredibly stupid , I forgot to set the drawingcacheenabled to true, so it could grab the actual image. Wow, that took a to find! But, eh, it works now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgot to do

```
captureButton.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
```

when saving my response, ergo, no bitmap was saved in the first place. Took me a while to track down, and I doubt this'll help anyone else since it was just a silly mistake of another problem.

Comment: Nice thing you post the answer :) don't forget to set as valide